# How to provide Federated authentication with Tenant's corporate IdP using Cognito user pool

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, aws-userpools

1. It's a multi-tenant B2B SaaS application. How can I provide the Ability to provide Federated authentication with Tenant's corporate IdP for some tenants only if they choose to? For other tenants, basic UN/Password flow is required.
2. Do I need to use a pool per tenant or a common pool should work here?
3. Also, I am not planning to use the Identity pool but only the user pool as we do not need to give direct access to AWS resources.