# IAM policy to restrict access folders in s3 bucket with tenant_id in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi-tenant system. The application allows for generating different sorts of reports. The users are authenticated in the Cognito user pool and have a JWT token (with tenant_id etc). I only want users of the same tenant to be able to access the reports stored in s3.  The reports are listed in the application for download but I would like to make sure that reports of another tenant can never be accessed.
For users to be able to access only their own reports, the s3 policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1487688853521",
    "Statement": [
       {
            "Sid": "Stmt1492075309356",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1487688849187",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/users/*/public/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

How should this be modified such that the tenant_id in JWT token can be used to match in the path for accessing documents inside bucket with a name like `"BUCKETNAME/tenants/${tenant_id}/*`
I believe `$tenant_id` needs to be replaced like `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:tenant_id}` or something similar to match with tenant_id custom attribute in the Cognito pool. Is this the right way?

Comment: Can you set up different identity pools for different tenants? Then you'd be able to use `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud` to map to different permission sets.

Comment: Thanks. We are considering using different user pools for different tenants.  can you explain how can cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud  be used and what exactly is it? also, do we have a list of valid Cognito variables allowed in IAM policies? @jingx

Comment: @jingx I would also like to know if custom attributes from Cognito can be used in IAM policies (for example fine-grained access control in Dynamo DB using leading keys based on an attribute called tenant_id in cognito)

Comment: `sub`, `aud`, `amr` may be the only three values currently available, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html

Comment: @jingx Alright. Does it mean that I need an identity pool per tenant in addition to user pool per tenant? Same goes for fine grained access control in dynamodb using leadingKeys?

Comment: @jingx Also, is cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud not possible to use with user pools and just with identity pools?

Comment: @jingx Look forward to your response

Comment: Yeah, the aud value comes from the identity pool. It's possible to control access from a user pool, but I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do that in an IAM policy with substitutions.

Comment: @jingx Alright. Thank you. Can you check this as well please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621664/how-to-provide-federated-authentication-with-tenants-corporate-idp-using-cognit